# 37 is not a valid SDK version

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, expo

At start i want to say that I'm a new player at react-native and android studio.
I create an expo project and apply template **tabs**. After this I try to start my app on Android emulator but it throw me a error: 37 is not a valid SDK version.Options are 35.0.0, 36.0.0
I updated an Android studio and SDK tools but it still throw me this error.
I have Android Studio 3.6.2.
I attached a screenshot iwth my Android SDK Tool settings.
[image]

Comment: there is no SDK 37, Android is only up to 29 with Android 11 (not yet released) being 30. I dont know where you are getting these numbers from

Answer (score 0):

In package.json change expo from

```
"dependencies": {
"expo": "~37.0.3",
"react": "~16.9.0",
"react-dom": "~16.9.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
```

to 33 or any older version

```
"dependencies": {
"expo": "^33.0.0",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I found solution. If you are using Android emulator on your Linux system, steps are as follow.

1. go to your emulator folder exmp. >> `~/Android/Sdk/emulator`
2. search for available Avd emulator >> `sudo ./emulator -list-avds`
3. wipe data from your emulator start it as new. I am using Pixel_3_API_24 !!IMPORTANT: this command will wipe all of your installed programs on your emulator and delete all your files which you ever put/download it >> `sudo ./emulator -avd Pixel_3_API_24 -wipe-data`
4. than start your expo from this command in your project `sudo expo start -c`

I hope this help you guys

Happy codding !~#$

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not due to your android SDK version (Since android doesn't have SDK 37 yet at the time I am writing the answer.)It happens whenever your expo app installed on the device/emulator does not support the **expo SDK** version you are working with. the most efficient way to solve this issue is -

- Update your expo app present on your device/emulator.
- Stop the expo and run your project again.

Answer (score 0):

Run `expo client:install:android`

You might need to update expo app on you device as well